# display recently modified items in a view

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, view

I am trying to create a view in SharePoint list for items that has been modified in last 5-10 min, and trigger an email based of that. I can take care of triggering email part using SharePoint designer workflow actions. just want to find out if we can filter view for items modified most recently.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, out of the box you can only view the last items that were modified at least today - 1. You can do so by modifying the view and in the filter, choose "Created", for the filter type make it Greater than or equal, and for the value type: [Today]-1 (wihout spaces).